# How to make JWT token based link as one time use link for Reset Password and Email Verification functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

## 1.  What I have done till now

I added reset password functionality in my project in which user gets the link in their respective email. I used user's hashed password as its secret key to make the link ONE TIME USE. So if the user change his password once than the hash changes and also the secret key making the token verification invalid which in turns makes the the link ONE TIME USE. As I used user's hashed password as its secret key I also have to pass user's `_id` with the token in the link so that at the time of verifying the token first I fetch the user's password hash with the help of the user's `_id` that I passed with the token in the link.

## 2.  What I want to do

Now it's time to add email verification functionality to my project and I am not getting any idea of how to make the verification link as one time link. And what if the users request multiple times for the email verification and I generate that many link and send it to the user's respective email.

## 3.  I thought of doing this

I thought of creating a database for email verification and insert the `user_Id` and `token` to that database each time the user requests for the verification and once the user click any of the requested links I make the user verified and delete all the token associated to the user's `user_Id` so that when the user clicks any of the link or the same link again the email is already verified and token is deleted so I can response "Invalid Link or Request" to the user.

## If the no. 3 is a legit mechanism I will implement same to no.  1

If the above mechanism is legit and good to go I would like to implement the same for my password reset functionality so that I no need to use user's password hash as the secret key and also not pass the user's `_id` in the link

#### Please also give suggestions if these both functionality can be done in a different way

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your reasoning.

Comment: @WiktorZychla so should I implement the no. 3 for password reset and Email verification?

Comment: IMO, For the password reset, you can continue going with the first approach for sending the hash password in JWT Token. In this way, you won't have to store the token in the database. If your database gets compromised, then all your tokens will be stolen and ultimately user data gets compromised.

Comment: @ajaygandhi as I am using hash password I also have to send user's id along with the token. 
If it's OK to send user's Id than should I use Point no 3 for email verification? whats your opinion on that